# Random sound in js

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

How to create a random sound in JavaScript and save it to the desktop?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "random sound".

Comment: Why did you tag jQuery??

Comment: It means that each seconds there is a different notes.

Comment: i thought we could do it with jquery

Comment: are you saying you want some sort of music creation application written in javascript? or totally random noise? what would you be saving to the desktop? any format? is there to be any user control?

Answer (score 3):

use a library like Riffwave: http://codebase.es/riffwave/

> "riffwave.js" is a tiny javascript library that encodes audio data to a format (PCM inside a RIFF container) that can be used to play synthesized sounds with the HTML5 audio element.

e.g. of a random sound generation

```
var data = []; 

for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    // fill data with random samples
    data[i] = Math.round(255 * Math.random()); 
}

var wave = new RIFFWAVE(data); // create the wave file

/*
     pass wave.dataURI property to a server page via POST and 
     then re-send the content along with the right headers 
     for a wav file so  to enforce download

     or just redirect your client using data:uri schema, like
     location.href =  wave.dataURI 
     (but this won't force the download in every browser)
*/
```